# Unity Crash on Instantiating prefab on Unity 5.6.4p4

Tags: unity-game-engine

we are facing a crash in our game during prefab instatiation, below is the crashlog.

```
Unknown:-2 libunity.00124d68 // resolves to GameObject::QueryComponentByType(Unity::Type const*) const
Unknown:-2 libunity.001de6d8 // resolves to CollectAndProduceClonedIsland(Object&, Transform*, vector_map<int, int, std::less<int>, stl_allocator<std::pair<int, int>, (MemLabelIdentifier)1, 16> >&)
Unknown:-2 libunity.001df368 // resolves to CloneObjectImpl(Object*, Transform*, vector_map<int, int, std::less<int>, stl_allocator<std::pair<int, int>, (MemLabelIdentifier)1, 16> >&)
Unknown:-2 libunity.001df274 // resolves to CloneObject(Object&)
Unknown:-2 libunity.00a56340 // resolves to Object_CUSTOM_Internal_CloneSingle(MonoObject*)
Unknown Unknown.0000ca04
Unknown:-2 Object.Internal_CloneSingle
<0x00030>:48 Object.Instantiate
<0x002eb>:747 DialogManager.CreateAndShowDialog
<0x0024b>:587 DialogManager.TryToShowNextDialog
<0x0013f>:319 DialogManager.Update
Unknown:-2 Object.runtime_invoke_void__this__
Unknown:-2 libmono.00021f23
mono_runtime_invoke:136 libmono.mono_runtime_invoke
Unknown:-2 libunity.004ec6a0
Unknown:-2 libunity.004dab50
Unknown:-2 libunity.001e1300
Unknown:-2 libunity.0031f8a8
Unknown:-2 libunity.005efc68
Unknown:-2 libunity.005f2a7c
Unknown:-2 base.000839fb
```

basically this looks like a crash happening while instantiating a prefab.

1. Does our unity version has anything to do with this? its 5.6.4p4.
2. We are loading this from an asset bundle. Is that the reason by any chance?
3. We are Instantiating this from a co-routine. Can this happen because of this?
4. Could this be a memory issue?

Please let me know if anyone has some context on this crash.
Thank you.

Comment: what happens if you try to instantiate a different prefab (maybe an empty one?). Also is it the Editor itself that crashes or just your game that stops running? If the latter are you getting any error messages in your console? What is the code you use to instantiate the prefab?

Comment: @remy_rm this is a crash that is happening in android with multiple prefabs. Also, it happens with specific devices. I use Instantiate(prefab) to instantiate

Comment: What are those specific devices? Are they devices with lower end specs? (and does it then work on higher end devices?)

Comment: @remy_rm Not low end.. but 70% are samsung devices

Comment: _IL2CPP: Fixed a crash in QueryComponentByType when animation was used with engine code stripping enabled and there was no Sprite Renderer component in any scene in the build._ from unity 2017.1.1 release notes.

Comment: Is the assetbundle made for that Version?

Comment: Can you please include some code so that we can help you better? Thank you!

Comment: @derHugo It the same

Comment: Also one more clue. I instantiate using a component

Comment: AssetBundles are created separately for each platform. Do you load android specific asset bundles or, maybe, created for other platforms (windows or ios)

Comment: @misher no, that's not the case

Comment: Please add the complete code where you obtain, load assetbundles and Instantiate the objects.

Comment: Have you tried casting it to a `GameObject`?